# Finding the rightmost non-zero digit in $770^{3520}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$770^{3520}$

I am trying to find right non zero most digit in above exp.

I divide the exp into $77^{3520}$ $*$ $10^{3520}$

and dont know what to do next....plz help

Comment: Write $77 = 70 + 7$. What happens when you expand $(70 + 7)^{3520}$? Which of these terms are multiples of $10$?

Comment: Also: if you look at the rightmost digits of $7, 7^2, 7^3, 7^4, 7^5, 7^6, \dots$, do you see a pattern? Can you explain it? Can you use this knowledge to find the rightmost digit of $7^{3520}$?

Comment: yes as u explained 3520 mod 4 equals 0 which means whatever the  rightmost digit of $7^{4}$ will be the right most digit of $7^{3520}$

Comment: which is 1 as $7^{4}$ equals 2401

Comment: Yes. Note that modulo $4$ we also have $4 \equiv 0$ so $7^{3520} \equiv 7^4 \equiv 7^0 = 1$, so you do not even have to compute $7^4$...

Comment: thanks very precisly explained

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  If you want the rightmost non zero digit there's no need to gently divide 770^N to 77^n x 10^n.  Be rough!  Take that 10^n, stomp on it, and toss it in the trash and forget about it altogether.  You need to find that last digit of 77^n and that's just a matter of finding the last digit of $7^{3520}$  which can be done quickly by trial and error ($7^2 -> 9; 9*7 -> 3; 3*7 -> 1$.  repeat) or by FLT.  $7^{\phi(10)} = 7^4 = 1 \mod 10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can discard the $10^{3520}$ term since we're looking for a non-zero digit. Now we know that (since $77=7\cdot 11$ and $11\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\, 10=1$):
\begin{align*}
77^{4k}\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,{10} &= 1\\
77^{4k+1}\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,{10} &= 7\\ 
77^{4k+2}\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,{10}&= 9\\
77^{4k+3}\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,{10}&= 3
\end{align*}
(we can prove these for example with congruences)
and since $3520 \,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,{4} = 0$ the first non-zero digit of $77^{3520}$ and also $770^{3520}$ is $1$.

Comment: helpful well explained

Answer (score 0):

You're right to start by dividing by 770 by 10. I'll just carry on from there...

$77^{3520}=(7*11)^{3520}$

If you multiply something by eleven, its last digit remains unchanged. ($x+10x=11x$; last digit of $10x$ is always zero) This means that the last digit of $77^{3520}$ is equal to that of $7^{3520}$.

The sequence with nth term $7^n mod 10$ (last digit of $7^n$) is as follows:

7, 9, 3, 1, 7, 9, 3, 1...

It repeats (for obvious reasons) and so where $n=3520$, $n$ could also be $3520 mod 4$ which is zero. This means that the last digit of $7^{3520}$ is one and this is the last non-zero digit of $770^{3520}$.